# render html from javascript rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, haml, html-safe

I Have a rendering of a partial that should be outputted to a div that is not displayed correctly.
I tried in my index.js.haml :

```
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{escape_javascript(raw render("details"))}');"
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{escape_javascript(raw render("details")).html_safe}');"
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{escape_javascript(raw render("details").html_safe)}');"
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{raw escape_javascript(raw render("details"))}');"
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{raw escape_javascript(raw render("details").html_safe)}');"
= "$('.modal-body').html('#{raw escape_javascript(raw render("details")).html_safe}');"
```

and they are all outputing the same following thing:

[image]

If I remove the escape_javascript, it ain't working anymore.

Comment: Try this `= $('.modal-body').html('#{escape_javascript(raw render("details")).html_safe}');`

Comment: I'm searching for solution. Mark accepted if you found answer.

Comment: I can't accept my answer before two days... But look at my answer, it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Emu who posted the answer in ERB I found a way of doing it in haml:

```
:plain
  $('.modal-body').html('#{j render partial: 'details'}'); // in HAML

$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render partial: 'details'%>'); //in ERB
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.modal-body').html('<%=j render partial: 'details' %>'); // in HTML

$('.modal-body').html('#{j render partial: 'details'}');  // in HAML
```

Comment: You have to add the :plain before and indent the haml line